# How to secure Rest API endpoint that is consumed by the frontend on same server?

Tags: rest, security, authentication, web

Imagine scenario where frontend, for example via ajax request gets data from Rest API and consumes it. How is the best way to secure that Rest API?

I was thinking about bearer token. But then again, bearer token can still be intercepted/dug from the code.

I was thinking also about CORS and allowing only same-origin header, but that again, can be  spoofed via curl etc..

I was also thinking about building token-ring system where the requester first has to announce his intent to read / write resource and then either be approved and given one use token to perform read/write or be denied. But that could end up being resource heavy and peformance hog.

What other options are there?

Answer (score 0):

We need some context for it. And question is why you need to secure data. Based on your requirement, the answer may be different..

If data you fetch is available publicly in your webpage for everyone, even if you use token you can't make it secure. Because anybody knows how web works can use token to capture data or parse your webpage simply.

If you want to limit API usage, then you can implement an API gateway and web firewall so nobody can abuse your API endpoint.